# one click, two 'click' event fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I just want to toggle some elements when a link is clicked:

This is how i am trying (But i don't really think that it matters much for this question what's inside the event function callback):

```
/* mostrar exceso de comentarios a peticion del usuario*/
$('.toggleComments').click(function(){
        console.log('.toggleComments');
        if($(this).parents('.helpContent').find('.commentHideble:visible').length > 0){
            $(this).text('+ <?=get_texto_clave('show_old_comments')?>').removeClass('toggleCommentsActive').append(' ('+$(this).parents('.helpContent').find('.commentHideble:not:visible').length+'+)');
        }else{
            $(this).text('- <?=get_texto_clave('hide_old_comments')?>').addClass('toggleCommentsActive');
        }
        $(this).parents('.helpContent').find('.commentHideble').slideToggle(100);

});
```

I even tried a boolean but gave me same result

```
/* mostrar exceso de comentarios a peticion del usuario*/


var ctoggle = false;
$('.toggleComments').click(function(){
    if(ctoggle == false){
        ctoggle = true;
        console.log('.toggleComments');
        if($(this).parents('.helpContent').find('.commentHideble:visible').length > 0){
            $(this).text('+ <?=get_texto_clave('show_old_comments')?>').removeClass('toggleCommentsActive').append(' ('+$(this).parents('.helpContent').find('.commentHideble:not:visible').length+'+)');
        }else{
            $(this).text('- <?=get_texto_clave('hide_old_comments')?>').addClass('toggleCommentsActive');
        }
        $(this).parents('.helpContent').find('.commentHideble').slideToggle(100);
        ctoggle = false;
    }
});
```

Why the log is being fired twice by click?

Comment: What's the HTML look like for this? Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Are you loading the HTML with ajax or something like that or just a regular load?

Comment: you can check at http://209.51.221.243/integracion/login.php its the blue button on top of the post comments.

Comment: @f01 regular load from the php

Comment: Ok. Have you tried e.preventDefault() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got the same chunk of jQuery twice in the page. Two binds=two fires.

Lines 499 and 1481.

Comment: But its only once in my code.. (re checked)

Comment: Look at the source and you'll see it's there twice.

Comment: OMG the file was imported twice. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

A jsfiddle page whould be helpfull but meanwhile you can try this:

```
$('.toggleComments').click(function(e){

    e.stopPropagation(); 

    console.log('.toggleComments');
    if($(this).parents('.helpContent').find('.commentHideble:visible').length > 0){
        $(this).text('+ <?=get_texto_clave('show_old_comments')?>').removeClass('toggleCommentsActive').append(' ('+$(this).parents('.helpContent').find('.commentHideble:not:visible').length+'+)');
    }else{
        $(this).text('- <?=get_texto_clave('hide_old_comments')?>').addClass('toggleCommentsActive');
    }
    $(this).parents('.helpContent').find('.commentHideble').slideToggle(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a class selector, it's not unlikely the click event is bubbling/propagating over several elements, all with the `toggleComments` class. `e.stopPropagation()` should help in your case.

`preventDefault` stops the click itself, so if the element is a hyperlink, best not use that method. If it's just a div, span or whatever, you can always return false. In jQuery, returning false stops event Propagation/bubbling *and* prevents default.